# $P$ is a prime ideal $\iff$ for $r, s \in R$ such that $rRs \subset P$, then $r \in P$ or $s \in P$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

If $P$ is an ideal in a not necessarily  commutative ring $R$, then the following conditions are equivalent:
a) $P$ is a prime ideal,
b) If $r,s\in R$ such that $rRs\subset P$ then $r\in P$ or $s\in P$.

I tried to prove it like this:

a)$\Rightarrow$ b)
let $P$ is prime ideal.
If $rRs\subset P$ then $\{r\}\subset P$ or $Rs\subset P$ then $r\in P$ or $Rs\in P$. If $1\in R$ then for $Rs\subset P$,$s\in P$ but if $1\notin R$ How can I prove it?

For b)$\Rightarrow$ a)
I couldn't find anything.

Comment: If ... then ... or ... then ... or makes for a confusing sentence.  Also, $Rs\in P$ does not make sense.  And it's weird to write $\{r\}\subseteq P$ for $r\in P$.  Maybe this can be brushed up to clarify what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

For $a)\Rightarrow b)$, you just need to use the prime condition once more, i.e. $Rs\subset P$ implies $R\subset P$ or $( s) \subset P$, and the first possibility is absurd as $P$ is proper. Thus $( s)\subset P$, i.e. $s\in P$.

For $b)\Rightarrow a)$, take $A,B\subset R$ ideals such that $AB\subset P$. If $A\subset P$ we are done. Otherwise, we have some $g\in A$ such that $g\notin P$. Now consider $gRs\subset AB\subset P$ for every $s\in B$. Then the assumption in $b)$ shows that $s\in P$ for every $s\in B$, i.e. $B\subset P$.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: $s = 1s\in Rs\subseteq P$ already says $s\in P$, so it seems no condition is needed.  The real problem is that the poster's reasoning up to that point doesn't hold.

Comment: @rschwieb you are right, I was implicitly thinking of the ideal $(s)$, not the set $\lbrace s\rbrace$, and then no extra step was needed.

Answer (score 1):

> If $rRs\subset P$ then $\{r\}\subset P$ or $Rs\subset P$

This really makes me suspect you are using the definition of prime ideal for commutative rings (that $rs\in P$ implies $r\in P$ or $s\in P$) which is not intended.

If you have any (noncommutative) prime ring that isn't a domain (so that $P=\{0\}$ is prime), then there exists $r,s\neq 0$ such that $rs=0$, but $r\notin \{0\}$ and $Rs\nsubseteq \{0\}$ because $s\neq 0$.

So you can see that the step you're taking there is not valid.

---

A correct definition of a prime ideal $P$ in a noncommutative ring is:

> If $A$ and $B$ are right ideals such that $AB\subseteq P$, then $A\subseteq P$ or $B\subseteq P$.

Using the right definition:

$a \implies b$

Suppose $rRs\subseteq P$.  Then $(rR)(sR)\subseteq P$, and so at least one of $Rr$ and $Rs$ is contained in $P$, and therefore at least one of $r,s$ is in $P$.

$\neg a\implies \neg b$

Since we have supposed that a) does not hold, there exists right ideals $A,B$ such that $AB\subseteq P$ but neither is contained in $P$.  Find $a\in A\setminus P$ and $b\in B\setminus P$.  Then $aRb=a(Rb)\subseteq AB\subseteq P$ shows that b) does not hold.

Comment: you are right. thanks. but I have a question. I can not understand this " Suppose rRs⊆P
. Then (Rr)(Rs)⊆P" How did you deduce that?

Comment: $P$ is an ideal!  $rRs$ is a subset of $P$ and $P$ is closed under left multiplication by arbitrary elements of $R$. This includes doing $R(rRs)=(Rr)(Rs)$.

Comment: Now I see, but I have one last question. if at least one of Rr and Rs is contained in P, why is at least one of r,s in P? if R was field the result is clear. But if not, how can you see it?

Comment: $r\in Rr\subseteq P$ or $s\in Rs\subseteq P$.  Nothing complicated.

Comment: if r ∈ Rr then ∃ a∈R such that r=ar then a is an identity element.  but can be 1∉R 
then can be r∉R. Isn't that right?

Comment: @elif "if $r\in Rr$ then $\exists a\in R$ such that $r=ar$, then $a$ is an identity element" It certainly acts like an identity on $r$'s left, but nobody would assume it is the identity element of the ring.  If you are not talking about rings with identity then I cannot guarantee the equivalence of the original conditions.  It is extremely rare to talk about any notion of prime ideals without assuming identity. If you originally intended to talk about rings without identity then you should have mentioned it in your original post (but you've missed the boat at this point.)

Comment: I wrote the question as it was written in the book. Since it was not mentioned in the book that there was an identity element I wanted to ask. Thank you

Comment: @elif If it's hard to tell if it is assumed or not, it's usually safe to assume identities are required.  If you need further help determining you're going to have to divulge what book you're talking about.

Comment: $Rr$ and $Rs$ are left ideals. You defined prime ideal in terms of right ideal. Anyway that is not why I commented. There are several equivalent definition of prime ideal, you picked the one which would be easiest to prove $(a)\implies (b)$. In most of textbook, prime ideal is defined as follows: If $A$ and $B$ are ideals such that $AB\subseteq P$, then $A\subseteq P$ or $B\subseteq P$.

Comment: @user264745 Thanks for spotting the typos. They are fixed.  Actually I think in the noncommutative texts I have, the authors always establish the equivalence of  definitions using left, right and two-sided ideals.  It would be rather silly to omit them anyhow.