# Characterization of prime rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, primality-test, herstein-theory

Let $R$ be a noncommutative ring without identity.

Recall that a ring $R$ is said to be a prime ring if $aRb=(0), a,b\in R$ implies that $a=0$ or $b=0$.

I have to prove that

1. $R$ is a prime ring

if and only if

2. if $A,B$ are two-sided ideals of R and $AB=(0)$ then either $A=(0)$ or $B=(0)$.

The implication from 1. to 2. is easy to establish, but I have difficulty with the converse implication.
I can't think of how this is true if $R$ is not unital.
This is an exercise contained in the book "Noncommutative rings" by Herstein.

Comment: If $aRb= 0$ did you try evaluating $(a)(b)?$

Comment: $(a)=RaR$? RaR doesn't contain $a$, because $R$ is not unital.

Comment: @mary I do not think the question was asked with the intention of considering rings without identity. There is no significant presence of "theory of prime ideals in rings without identity" even in noncommutative ring theory books.  With the assumption of identity, I think your question is trivially different from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4718299/29335 and you would get your answer there.

Comment: @rschwieb thanks for your answer! I think that without identity the property is harder to prove but also true.

Comment: @mary Maybe, but beware on spending a lot of time on a question that may not have been asked.

Comment: Fixed a nonzero element in a noncommutative ring without identity, there exist a procedure to construct an ideal that contains this element?

Comment: @mary Of course?  $(a)=a\mathbb Z+aR+Ra+RaR$...